# How to click on the links which contain javascript

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I would like to click on the link name "12FDEW01" and read the data from right side page in the link

```
'https://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/CaseForm.aspx?  xsl=main.xsl&CaseID=773013618'
```

it can be access through Vehicle 2 --> Vehicle Exterior -->Crush Profile
but internal links contain the java script. how can read the data by clicking on the text.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Ie()
url_database = 'https://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/CaseForm.aspx?  xsl=main.xsl&CaseID=773013618'
driver.get(url_database)
aElements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
for name in aElements:
    print(name)
    name.click()    
    name.get_attribute('value')
```

HTML code:

```
<ul>
   <li><a class="menu" onclick="toggleswitch(this)" href="javascript:parent.loadViewer('VE.xsl','VehicleExterior‌​Forms','CDC','',2,-1‌​,1,'247573099','Vehi‌​cle 2 Exterior - CDC - 12FDEW01',773013618)">12FDEW01</a><img src="img/info.png" alt="&#xA;Event 1 : Struck Vehicle 1" title="&#xA;Event 1 : Struck Vehicle 1"></img></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: share the HTML code, image, problem statement ..

Comment: HTML:    <ul>
                                          <li><a class="menu" onclick="toggleswitch(this)" href="javascript:parent.loadViewer('VE.xsl','VehicleExteriorForms','CDC','',2,-1,1,'247573099','Vehicle 2 Exterior - CDC - 12FDEW01',773013618)">12FDEW01</a><img src="img/info.png" alt="&#xA;Event 1 : Struck Vehicle 1" title="&#xA;Event 1 : Struck Vehicle 1"></img></li>
                                       </ul>                                   problem is name.click() gives me error. so how can I click on the text "12FDEW01" from site

Comment: hey do you want to read img tag data? this one :- <img src="img/info.png" alt="&#xA;Event 1 : Struck Vehicle 1" title="&#xA;Event 1 : Struck Vehicle 1"></img>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below XPath :-

```
//a[@class='menu' and contains(@onclick,'toggleswitch(this)') and contains(.,'12FDEW01') and contains(@href,'javascript')]
```

If still the problem exists then use JavascriptExecutor . It will operate directly through JS. It should work. I am giving an example to click any element using JavascriptExecutor

Code should be like below :-

```
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class='menu' and contains(@onclick,'toggleswitch(this)') and contains(.,'12FDEW01') and contains(@href,'javascript')]') 
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

create your Xpath as an object and then pass array value as below :-

```
(//a[@class='menu' and contains(@onclick,'toggleswitch(this)') and contains(.,'12FDEW01') and contains(@href,'javascript')])[1]
```

Change value of array 1 or 2 as per required

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: updated my answer .. plz try with JavascriptExecutor

Comment: your updated code is working fine but I  faced one more issue 12FDEW01 has twice in different hierarchy. how can handle this..like    CDC-->12FDEW01   and Crush Profile --> 12FDEW01    HTML code as follows    ----

Comment: <li>CDC
                                                         
                                       <ul>
                                          <li><a class="menu" onclick="toggleswitch(this)" href="javascript:parent.loadViewer('VE.xsl','VehicleExteriorForms','CDC','',2,-1,1,'247573099','Vehicle 2 Exterior - CDC - 12FDEW01',773013618)">12FDEW01</a><img src="img/info.png" alt="&#xA;Event 1 : Struck Vehicle 1" title="&#xA;Event 1 : Struck Vehicle 1"></img></li>
                                       </ul>
                                    </li>

Comment: <li>Crush Profile
                                                         
                                       <ul>
                                          <li><a class="menu" onclick="toggleswitch(this)" href="javascript:parent.loadViewer('VE.xsl','VehicleExteriorForms','Crush','',2,-1,1,-1,'Vehicle 2 Exterior - Crush - Profile 1',773013618)">12FDEW01</a></li>
                                       </ul>
                                    </li>

Comment: you want which one Vehi‌​cle 2 Exterior - CDC - or Vehicle 2 Exterior - Crush - Profile 1',77301

Comment: I have updated my answer where you can select your element by array value.

Comment: Thanks Shubam Jain... your suggestion worked well...but one small correction driver.find_element_by_xpath  it has to be driver.find_elements_by_xpath.  instead of element it should be elements

Comment: I am java guy. Created code for you in python :) .. well thanks for pointing out .. will take care .. please accept the answer. It will help me .. refer link if you don't know how to accept the answer -
 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work